# complete space $\mathbb{B}[a,b]$ in $॥.॥_\infty$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to show that $\mathbb{B}[a,b]$ , the space of all bounded complex valued functions is complete. I know that it is easy consequence if we show it to be closed subspace of $L^{\infty} [a,b]$ or more general topological result that $B(X,Y)$ is closed subset of $Y^X$ in uniform metric if $Y$ is complete.But I want to begin with a Cauchy sequence and show that it converges to a bounded function. Let $f_n$ be a  Cauchy sequence. Then due to uniform convergence $f_n (x)$ converges pointwise to , say, $f(x)\in \mathbb{C}$ . I am stuck at showing that $f$ is bounded .

Comment: Aside: $Y^X$ is not a complete metric space with the uniform metric.

Comment: Hint: $d(f_m(x), f(x)) = \lim_{n\to\infty} d(f_m(x), f_n(x))$.

Comment: I don't think results about $L^\infty[a,b]$ tell you anything about $\mathbb B [a,b].$ The norm for the latter is not the $L^\infty$ norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's be careful. The norm on $\mathbb B = \mathbb B[a,b]$ is not the $L^\infty$ norm. Rather it is the strict sup-norm:

$$\|f\|_{\mathbb B} = \sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f(x)|.$$

From this we see $f_n \to f$ in $\mathbb B$ iff $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[a,b].$

Now suppose $f_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb B.$ Isn't that the same thing as saying $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy on $[a,b]?$ And if $f_n$ is uniformly Cauchy, isnt' it also _____?

Comment: ok I got it!! thanks

Comment: Does essential supremum coincides strict supremum in case of $C[a,b]$ ?

Comment: Yes it does. But of course $\mathbb B$ is not a subset of $C[a,b].$